# Non-root read access to /dev/mem by kmem group members fails

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm trying to read physical memory as a non-root user using `/dev/mem`. Checking the permissions of `/dev/mem`:

```
~/w/e/setup ❯❯❯ ls -lha /dev/ | grep mem
crw-r-----   1 root kmem        1,     1 Oct 15 09:29 mem
```

From my understanding, a member of the `kmem` group should be allowed to read from `/dev/mem`. I check my group memberships:

```
~/w/e/setup ❯❯❯ groups
docker users video uucp kmem wheel autologin
```

The current user is a member of the `kmem` group, so I try to read a bit from `/dev/mem`:

```
~/w/e/setup ❯❯❯ head /dev/mem | hexdump -C
head: cannot open '/dev/mem' for reading: Operation not permitted
```

To my surprise, the operation is not permitted. The same operation works when I login as root.

Can someone explain, why I cannot read from `/dev/mem` as a member of group `kmem`?
How can I enable non-root read-only access to `/dev/mem` for a specific user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/dev/mem` can only be opened [by processes with `CAP_SYS_RAWIO`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.14/source/drivers/char/mem.c#L786); `head`, not running as root, doesn’t have that capability. You can “fix” this using `setcap` (but only do this on a copy of the binary...):

```
cp /usr/bin/head .
sudo setcap cap_sys_rawio+ep head
./head /dev/mem | hexdump -C
```

Enabling access to `/dev/mem` for a specific user thus involves group membership (so that the device can be opened) and binary capabilities.