# Is memory mapped I/O only used internally by OS, not exposed to and used by programmers on top of Linux?

Tags: linux, io, memory-mapped-file

In Operating System Concepts, memory mapped files and memory mapped I/O are two different things. See below about memory mapped I/O.

To use memory mapped files, we have `mmap()`.

To use memory mapped I/O, what functions can we use? Is memory mapped I/O only used internally by OS, not exposed to and used by programmers on top of Linux?

Thanks.

> In the case of I/O, as mentioned in Section 1.2.1, each I/O controller includes
>   registers to hold commands and the data being transferred. Usually, special I/O
>   instructions allow data transfers between these registers and system memory.
>   To allow more convenient access to I/O devices, many computer architectures
>   provide **memory-mapped I/O**. In this case, ranges of memory addresses are
>   set aside and are mapped to the device registers. Reads and writes to these
>   memory addresses cause the data to be transferred to and from the device
>   registers. This method is appropriate for devices that have fast response times,
>   such as video controllers. In the IBM PC, each location on the screen is mapped
>   to a memory location. Displaying text on the screen is almost as easy as writing
>   the text into the appropriate memory-mapped locations.

...

> **How can the processor give commands and data to a controller to
>   accomplish an I/O transfer?** The short answer is that the controller has one
>   or more registers for data and control signals. The processor communicates
>   with the controller by reading and writing bit patterns in these registers. One
>   way in which this communication can occur is **through the use of special
>   I/O instructions** that specify the transfer of a byte or word to an I/O port
>   address. The I/O instruction triggers bus lines to select the proper device and
>   to move bits into or out of a device register. Alternatively, the device controller
>   can support **memory-mapped I/O**. In this case, the device-control registers
>   are mapped into the address space of the processor. The CPU executes I/O
>   requests using the standard data-transfer instructions to read and write the
>   device-control registers at their mapped locations in physical memory.

Comment: Isn't the `dev` filesystem what you're supposed to use to connect with I/O controllers of all sorts?

Answer (score 10):

On Linux, MMIO is possible from user-space using `mmap` on `/dev/mem`. For example, the X server does

```
fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
if (ioBase == NULL) {
    ioBase = (volatile unsigned char *) mmap(0, 0x20000,
                                             PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                                             MAP_SHARED, fd, ioBase_phys);
}
close(fd);
```

in some cases. This is going out of fashion though and the kernel strictly controls what can be done using this type of access: accessing `/dev/mem` [requires `CAP_SYS_RAWIO`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475807/86440), and distribution kernels nowadays tend to be built with [`STRICT_DEVMEM`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.14/source/lib/Kconfig.debug#L2002) and `IO_STRICT_DEVMEM` which restrict access *via* `/dev/mem` to a few ranges in memory, either required for DOSEMU or X, or mapped to devices and otherwise unused (*i.e.* providing MMIO for a device which isn’t handled by a driver).

Comment: By the definition quoted in the question, the framebuffer counts as memory-mapped I/O space.  So there's another `mmap()` possibility.

Comment: Thanks. Does MMIO map controller's registers and memory to virtual memory addresses or physical memory addresses? Does MMIO involve virtual memory, or just physical memory?

Comment: The advantage of memory mapped file over standard IO system calls is to avoid copying from kernel cache/buffer to userspace buffer. Is the advantage of MMIO over port I/O also similar?

Comment: MMIO, viewed from the CPU’s perspective, is based on physical addresses, which can be mapped to virtual (linear) addresses if necessary. Viewed from the device’s perspective, it uses physical addresses, unless an IOMMU is involved. `/dev/mem` uses physical addresses only.

Comment: For MMIO you definitely want to avoid caches ;-). However the main advantage of MMIO over port I/O is that the number of available ports is small, and that accessing other devices’ memory using port I/O would be prohibitively slow (think of multi-gigabyte GPUs).

Comment: So do you mean that MMIO doesn't need virtual memory to work? Why "accessing other devices’ memory using port I/O would be prohibitively slow "?

Comment: Whether MMIO needs virtual memory depends on how you access memory. All CPU to memory accesses use linear addresses, so yes, you do end up needing virtual memory, but it might not be apparent in the way you use it; for example using `/dev/mem`, you only reason about physical addresses. Port I/O limits you to double-digit MB/s transfers (*e.g.* 16.7 MB/s for hard drives), and takes a significant amount of CPU to do so; that translates to one minute per gigabyte...

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why "accessing other devices’ memory using port I/O would be prohibitively slow " in terms of mechanism, instead of how slow it is.

Comment: The mechanism involved in port I/O, on x86, is a pair of instructions, [`IN`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/in) and [`OUT`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/out), with string-oriented variants. To write to a device’s memory, you issue `OUT` instructions; since the number of ports is limited, you’d typically write an index to one port, and the corresponding value to another. This can be optimised in a few ways, but it can’t be made very fast at all, and the CPU is heavily involved.

Answer (score 4):

Memory mapped I/O is done by `mmap()`ing a region of a file and then using the mapped data.

If you use a modern OS, the OS does most I/O mmapp'ing internally:

- map parts of the file into a transient kernel area
- `copyout()` the mapped data to the user address space. This causes the file content to be faulted into the transient memory area of the kernel.
- unmap the region

BTW: if you are referring to accessing hardware from user space, this is usually done e.g. by the X Server that `mmap()`s the hardware from the graphics board and accesses it from user space.

The device registers are accessible as memory addresses in that case and you just write code that looks as if you were inside the kernel. In other words: you do not use read() or write(), but just dereference pointers that point to the addresses of the hardware registers.

Comment: I would not use the term  memory mapped IO in relation to UNIX while talking about hardware access. If you however like to access hardware from user space, you need special privileges to be allowed to `mmap()` the addresses that are used by interface hardware. Then you can use the hardware from user space as if you were in the kernel.

Comment: @StephenKitt In MMIO, are the device controllers' registers and memory exposed as device files,  so that system calls including read(), write(), and mmap() can apply to the device files?

Comment: I added  an explanation on how the device registers are accessed in such a case.

Comment: Obviously the quoted text refers to memory mapped I/O in the hardware sense. Instead of the "special I/O instructions", of which the 8086 IN and OUT instructions are an example, the hardware is designed so that the I/O device registers appear in the memory address space, and normal memory access instructions like MOV are used. This is done in the in-kernel device driver, and no files are involved. The Operating System Concepts book is not a Unix-specific book, but intends to "provide a solid theoretical foundation for understanding operating systems."

Comment: libdrm would also be worth mentioning - it's what the Mesa OpenGL drivers use to map video memory into a user process (and is probably a wrapper around a kernel interface).  Then other drivers could also provide kernel interfaces where appropriate, such as the RDMA interface wrapped in the ibverbs and rdmacm libraries (though that's probably a bit different - there, a user process registers a region of its virtual memory locked to be resident for the RDMA card to read/write directly).